# How to differentiate between root and every other sub route in nginx?

Tags: nginx, routes, location

I am trying to make my site https://example.com/ to point to /var/location2/homepage.html and every other subroute https://example.com/abcd etc. to point to /var/location1 (where I have hosted my single page application). What should the location strings be- I tried the following, it does not work, the location ~* /.* overrides location / and points every URL to /var/location1. I want a catch all subroutes rather than individually say location /route1, location /route2 etc in the location string to capture all the subroutes to point to /var/location1.

```
    location ~* /.* {
        root /var/location1/;
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/location2/;
        try_files $uri  /homepage.html =404;
    }
```

Comment: `location /` is the catch-all location, and `location = /` matches only the `https://example.com/` URL. What about the resources required by `homepage.html`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I  loaded resources through public urls also hosted on my Single page app on location2